# Dynamically Populated JSON Heirarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynamic

I'm trying to create a div element that is populated with a title, image, and description dynamically using JSON. I got it to work when it was just those three elements for each whole element, but then I wanted to add some attributes to each of the three minor elements.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? As it is, it is only populating the first item of the iteration, and no more after that. Furthermore, the class attribute for the p tag is not populating, not even as undefined.

I am extremely new to JSON, please help me out here =)
I'm sure there's something I mistyped or didn't think through well enough, but I am stumped.

The ITEMS:

```
    var json = {
        "items": [

     /* Item One */
     {
         "title": 
          {
             "text": "Title",
             "class": "titleClass"
          }
         ,

         "image": 
          {
             "src": "imgs/mail.png",
             "class": "imageClass"
          }
         ,

         "description": 
             {
             "text": "Author",
             "class": "authorClass"
             }
         ,
     },


     /* Item Two */
     {
         "title": 
             {
            "text": "Title2",
            "class": "titleClass"
             }
         ,

         "image": 
             {
             "src": "img/money.png",
             "class": "imageClass"
             }
         ,

         "description": 
             {
            "text": "Author2",
            "class": "authorClass"
             }
         ,}]};
```

The code to iterate items:

```
    var news = document.getElementsByClassName("item-container")[0];
    var items = json.items;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        /* Title */
        var h2 = document.createElement("h2");
        h2.innerHTML = items[i].title.text;
        news.appendChild(h2);

            /* Class */
            var titleClass = document.createAttribute('class');
            titleClass.value = items[i].title.class;
            h2.setAttributeNode(titleClass);                

        /* Image */
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var src = document.createAttribute('src');
        src.value = items[i].image.src;
        img.setAttributeNode(src);
        news.appendChild(img);

            /* Class */    
            var imageClass = document.createAttribute('class');
            imageClass.value = items[i].image.class;
            img.setAttributeNode(imageClass);

        /* Description */
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML = items[i].description.text;
        news.appendChild(p);

            /* Class */
            var descClass = document.createAttribute('class');
            descClass.value = items[i].description.class;
            p.setAttributeNote(descClass);

    };
```

HTML:

```
            <div class="item-container">
            </div>
```

CSS:

There is no CSS yet, I was attempting to get this working before applying styles.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace:

```
p.setAttributeNote(descClass);
```

with:

```
p.setAttributeNode(descClass); //"...Node" instead of "...Note"
```

When a loop iterates just one time, ask yourself if all the JS code is valid and start to look for the mistake there where the code stopped to work properly.

Hope it helps!